# Sitecore 9.1.1 Xp scaled (XP1) installation on premises steps

Tags: sitecore-client

I am trying to install sitecore xp1 on premises where I am facing lots of challenges. I'm afraid about the order of installing sitecore xp1. I am following the below order, also successfully installed the **"Xconnect.Collection and xconnect.collection.search"**. I need to make sure I am going in right way.

1. XConnect-Solr.json and Sitecore-Solr.json
2. createcert.json  (for each one of the installation in below )
3. XConnect-xp1-collection.json
4. XConnect-xp1-collectionsearch.json
5. XConnect-xp1-referencedata.json
6. XConnect-xp1-marketingautomation.json
7. XConnect-xp1-marketingautomationreporting.json
8. xconnect-xp1-CortexProcessing.json
9. xconnect-xp1-CortexReporting.json
10. sitecore-xp1-rep.json
11. sitecore-xp1-prc.json
12. IdentityServer.json
13. sitecore-xp1-cm.json
14. sitecore-xp1-cd.json

I am not sure about how to install the **IdentityServer.json** and what is the value for **SitecoreIdentityCert**  parameter?

what is the use of **Role-Remote.json** file?

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 5.3 at page 46 of the [Installation Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/2EB5DDA7392D4FACAF09A6CBAC0BABD7.ashx) for Sitecore XP 9.1 Update-1 describes the steps to install a scaled Sitecore XP platform (XP1) on premises.

As highlighted in the document:

> You must first install the `sitecore-solr.json` and the `xconnect-solr.json` deployment configurations. Then you must install the rest of the Sitecore server roles deployment configurations and these can then be installed in any order.

The `IdentityServer.json` configuration is used to install the Identity Server application. The `SitecoreIdentityCert` parameter is the name of the IdentityServer server certificate. This is an example of installation command (with the minimum required parameters to execute successfully):

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\IdentityServer.json -SitecoreIdentityCert "XPScaled910.identityserver" -Package "C:\resourcefiles_sc911\Sitecore.IdentityServer 2.0.1 rev. 00166 (OnPrem)_identityserver.scwdp.zip" -AllowedCorsOrigins "mywebsite.example.com"
```

The `Role-Remote.json` configuration file is part of the remote distributed Sitecore Installation Framework (SIF) deployment templates. These templates can be used to deploy Sitecore Experience Platform remotely to a scalable distributed server cluster from a single workstation or server. The `Role-Remote.json` configuration is included for all Sitecore server roles deployment configurations. Its inclusions are defined in the `Includes` object in the distributed configuration files (ie. `XP1-Distributed.json`).